# auto_prepend_file not working for php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file here, and it seems that it's only adding the html files whenever I prepend. I have searched, changed, and done everything, I just can't get it! Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:txt)$>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>

php_value date.timezone 'America/Los_Angeles'

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/u684233983/public_html/includes/block.php" 
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/u684233983/public_html/includes/particles.html" 
php_value auto_append_file "/home/u684233983/public_html/includes/particlesEnd.html" 

<Files VPN.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files>  
<Files CheckUser.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files> 
<Files CheckIP.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files> 
<Files Whitelist.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files> 
<Files Payment-Success.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files> 
<Files Admin.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files> 
<Files log.php>
php_value auto_prepend_file none 
php_value auto_append_file none 
</Files>
```

It's not adding the "blocked.php" (Yes, I checked. It's in that directory)
It's adding particles.html, and particlesEnd.html though.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` only prepends one file (i.e. can't be used multiple times, or with a list of files), if you want to prepend multiple files then have a single file containing `require()` calls to pull in other files. `auto_append_file` behaves in the same way. See bugs [#3293](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=3293), [#25207](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25207), [#64484](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64484), etc..

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason, when I changed directories, it started working. In .htaccess, I changed it to append, and made it the last in the list.